# Mediapipe "The system cannot find the file specified" While Trying to Run the Hello World During Installation

Tags: c++, bash, installation, mediapipe

I'm installing Mediapipe on Windows 10 for c++ and I'm %90 sure I've set up everything correctly. I'm following the guide here: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-windows

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_foreign_cc' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "c2cdcf55ffaf49366725639e45dedd449b8c3fe22b54e31625eb80ce3a240f1e"
DEBUG: Repository rules_foreign_cc instantiated at:
  D:/mediapipe/WORKSPACE:43:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:355:31: in <toplevel>
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_absl' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_benchmark' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11_bazel' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_protobuf' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_google_googletest' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'com_github_gflags_gflags' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_apple' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_rules_swift' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'build_bazel_apple_support' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'xctestrunner' because it already exists.
DEBUG: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/repo.bzl:124:14:
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11' because it already exists.
DEBUG: Rule 'rules_cc' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments sha256 = "691a29db9c336349e48e04c5c2f4873f2890af5cbfa6e51f4de87fefe6169294"
DEBUG: Repository rules_cc instantiated at:
  D:/mediapipe/WORKSPACE:36:13: in <toplevel>
Repository rule http_archive defined at:
  C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:355:31: in <toplevel>
WARNING: D:/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/BUILD:54:24: in cc_library rule //mediapipe/framework:calculator_cc_proto: target '//mediapipe/framework:calculator_cc_proto' depends on deprecated target '@com_google_protobuf//:cc_wkt_protos': Only for backward compatibility. Do not use.
WARNING: D:/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/tool/BUILD:184:24: in cc_library rule //mediapipe/framework/tool:field_data_cc_proto: target '//mediapipe/framework/tool:field_data_cc_proto' depends on deprecated target '@com_google_protobuf//:cc_wkt_protos': Only for backward compatibility. Do not use.
INFO: Analyzed target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: C:/users/dillo/_bazel_dillo/hr7sucjp/external/com_github_gflags_gflags/BUILD:16:30: Executing genrule @com_github_gflags_gflags//:gflags_completions_h failed: (Exit -1): bash.exe failed: error executing command (from target @com_github_gflags_gflags//:gflags_completions_h) c:\tools\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -c ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
Action failed to execute: java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/process.cc(202): CreateProcessW("c:\tools\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe" -c "source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; awk '{ gsub(/@GFLAGS_NAMESPACE@/, \"gflags\"); print; }' external/com_github_gflags_gflags/src/gflags_completions.h.in > bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/com_github_gflags_gflags/gflags_completions.h"): The system cannot find the file specified.
 (error: 2)
Target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 77.898s, Critical Path: 77.44s
INFO: 209 processes: 128 internal, 81 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I've completely reinstalled Python and I've made sure to set up my path variables, can anyone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: The error is in that command `c:\tools\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe`. Do you have msys installed with bash? Do you have all those files required by the command already present in your system?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes, I have msys installed with path set to D:\mysys2\usr\bin. Here's the command I'm running, if that helps:

bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="C://Users//dillo//AppData//Local//Programs//Python//Python310//python.exe" mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world

Comment: New error woooooo!!! Thanks a a ton for pointing it out @kiner_shah ! I changed the folder name of mysys2 to msys64 and moved it into a new folder c:\tools to so that it would use that path, and now I have a new error not relating to msys :D If you know how I can set the folder for mediapipe to use with msys please do tell

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kiner_shah for pointing out what the error was:

If you are getting this error it's because mediapipe is trying to access the msys folder at the wrong location, so all you have to do is make it the *right* location. I moved my mysys2 folder from D:/mysys2, to the path that was showing the error: "c:\tools\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe" by making a tools folder in c:, renaming mysys2 to msys64, then moving that folder to the previously created tools folder.